# How to append an HTML to an existing file without using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to add the contents of one HTML file (the complete file including the tags and all) into a div? A way which uses pure JavaScript? Or is the only way to append lots of elements individually and make it a function maybe?

Comment: Easy. Make ajax request, append loaded string where you need.

Comment: It's very easy to do without jQuery, but if the HTML to be inlined is valid, it will contain <html> <head> and <body> elements that you shouldn't insert into another HTML document.

Comment: @Touffy hmm... well I can skip that it seems and thank you for the response!

Comment: @dfsq I only have the front end and I am just starting out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with ajax...but there is a catch. The HTML you load should not have `<html>` or `<head>` tags etc...

Main page:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Ajax Wizardry</title>
<script>
  function ajax(requestedForm,target) {
    var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById(target).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
      console.log("Content Updated");
    }
    console.log("ajax status: "+xmlhttp.status);
  }

xmlhttp.open("GET",requestedForm,true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("action=fetch");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

      <input type='button' value='Ajax Magic' onclick='ajax(`stufftoloadintodiv.html`,`target_1`)' />

<div id='target_1'></div>

</body>
</html>
```

stufftoloadintodiv.html contents

```
<p style='color:red;'>Hello World</p>
```

What I have done here is create a function called 'ajax' that accepts 2 variables. The first is the path to the file you want to load, the second is the intended target element id. So if you had `<div id='biscuits'></div>` and you wanted to load the contents of 'digestive.html' then you would just need to call `ajax('digestive.html','biscuits')`

Answer (score 1):

**a.html:**

```
<html> 
  <body>
  <h1>Put here your HTML content before insertion of b.js.</h1>
      ...

  <script src="customscript.js"></script>

      ...

  <p>And here whatever content you want afterwards.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

**customscript.js:**

```
document.write('\
\
    <h1>Add your HTML code here</h1>\
\
     <p>Notice however, that you have to escape LF's with a '\', just like\
        demonstrated in this code listing.\
    </p>\
\
');
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution without javascript would be to reference file from an iframe. Using this approach you don't need to worry about the HTML structure of the file.